# How to use the easySlicer plugin?

Tags: plugin

I have installed the [easySlicer plugin](http://tiddlyvault.tiddlyspot.com/#EasySlicer) as well as the required E.A.S.E plugin in my TiddlyWiki (Version 2.6.4). I installed the plugins manually by copying the source-code and addind the `systemConfig`-tag. They are enabled, and everything seems fine, except that I see no effect whatsoever. Since there is no documentation I can find, can someone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer (with a hint from [here](https://groups.google.com/group/TiddlyWiki/browse_thread/thread/930de4b38f2ccc0a?hl=nl)). After installing the plugin, you have to open the shadow-tiddler `ToolbarCommands` and add the word `slice` (not `slicer`, as it says in the linked post) to the end of the `EditToolbar`-row.